# Template tag for /page/# structure

Tags: page-template, conditional-content

I'm trying to find a template page (or conditional statement) that will target:

> http://url.com

but not

> http://url.com/page/2/

home.php and front-page.php seem to target both. The front page displays my latest posts.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress provides `is_paged()` which returns true on any archive or blog that stretches over multiple pages. This isn't what you want, but the [`is_paged` Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged) tells us where to go:

> If you need to check which page of the blog you are on, you can look in $wp_query->query_vars['paged']. Remember that inside functions you might have to global $wp_query first.

So, you should be able to use this snippet to only show something on the first page:

```
global $wp_query;
$my_paged_page = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'];
if ( $my_paged_page == 1 ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! is_paged(); was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Great. Make sure to read the Codex as it seemed from your question that `is_paged()` would return TRUE on both the example URLs you listed.